# Ezcontour in Matlab missing contours

Tags: matlab, plot, mixture-model

I've used the `gmdistribution` to fit data to a Gaussian mixture model. I wanted to plot a contour plot https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Pdb.jpg where the contours are obviously missing. For a 1D problem I found `fplot`, but now I'm stumped.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem when I wrote an EM algorithm for gaussian mixtures.  Here is the snippet of code that fixed it in my case:

```
for l=1:k
        zz=gmdistribution(MU(l,:),SIG(:,:,l),PI(l));
        ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(zz,[x y]),[minx1 maxx1],[miny1 maxy1],250);
end
```

The key is to increase `N`:

```
ezcontour(...,N) plots FUN over the default domain using an N-by-N
grid. The default value for N is 60.
```

Comment: Ok, I tested for too low values of grid elements; e.g. >100. I see now that >250 is optimal. Thanks.